# Terminating app due to an uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

I am tracking crashes in my app.  This particular crash gives me the error "Terminating app due to an uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'".  The weird thing is i can't seem to recreate the crash using my device or simulator but in my analytics it shows that this crash happens a lot.

This is code where the crash is happening:

```
indicator.startAnimation()
let audioData = NSData(contentsOfURL: EditSongViewController.url.urlComplete!)
let dataImage: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(songImage.image!, 1.0)!

let imageFile = PFFile(name: "photo.jpg", data: dataImage)
let audioFile = PFFile(name: "song.mp4", data: audioData)
audioFile.saveInBackground()
imageFile.saveInBackground()

let testObject = PFObject(className: "PrivateSongs")
testObject["songFile"] = audioFile
testObject["image"] = imageFile
testObject["username"] = PFUser.currentUser().username
testObject["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
testObject["title"] = self.songTitleText.text
testObject["songInfo"] = self.songInfoText.text
if RecordViewController.fileURL.songLyrics != nil {
    testObject["lyrics"] = RecordViewController.fileURL.songLyrics
}
if (isPrivate == true) {
    testObject["isPrivate"] = true
} else {
    testObject["isPrivate"] = false
}

testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (success, error) -> Void in
    if (success) {

        if self.chartsSwitch.on {
            let chart = PFObject(className: "Songs")
            chart["artistName"] = PFUser.currentUser().username
            chart["songFile"] = audioFile
            chart["title"] = self.songTitleText.text
            chart["picture"] = imageFile
            chart["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            chart["likes"] = 0
            if RecordViewController.fileURL.songLyrics != nil {
                chart["lyrics"] = RecordViewController.fileURL.songLyrics
            }
            chart.saveInBackground()

        }
        PostViewControler.share.shareUrl = audioFile.url!
        self.postButton.hidden = true
        self.addPictureButton.hidden = true
        self.indicator.stopAnimation(false, completion: nil)
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ShareViewController") , animated: true)

    } else {
        self.indicator.stopAnimation(false, completion: nil)
        self.helper.showErrorAlert("Couldn't save your song please try again.")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is `Only run on the main thread!`. The reason is you update UI in background thread (`testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (success, error) -> Void in`). Check your updating UI task, such as hide button, stop animation, navigate..., and move it to main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
/* Your UI code */
});
```

Comment: ok thats what i figured but I'm wondering why i can't seem to trigger the crash but in my crash analytics this happens frequently.  I'm doing the exact same thing my users are doing but the app doesn't crash for me.

Comment: I guess it should delay to update your UI, because you execute an update in background thread